# How do I display static columns with post data in bootstrap datatable?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I have just checked bootstrap datatable with a server side script. Here I used POST data to display my data table. Its no problem and working properly for me.

This is my javascript part -

```
$('#list-account').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
       "url": "includes/process_list_account.php",
       "type": "POST"
    },
    "columns": [
       { "data": "domain_name" },
       { "data": "username" },
       { "data": "contact_email" },
       { "data": "contact_number" },
       { "data": "date_registered" },
       { "data": "domain_expired", "class": "text-center"}
   ]
});
```

My problem is how can I display two static table columns along with post data. One for a same image for all rows in the table and other one for a same link to all rows. Is it possible with this?

some thing like this -

```
<tr>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>       
    <td><a href="mylink.html">my link</a></td>      
    <td><a href=""><img src="images/icon.png"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>       
    <td><a href="mylink.html">my link</a></td>      
    <td><a href=""><img src="images/icon.png"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>....</td>       
    <td><a href="mylink.html">my link</a></td>      
    <td><a href=""><img src="images/icon.png"></a></td>
</tr>
```

**UPDATE :** 
I tried it with `columns.render` -

```
    $('#cpanel-account').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
                "url": "includes/process_cpanel_details.php",
                "type": "POST"
        },
        "columns": [
                { "data": "domain_name" },
                { "data": "cpanel_username" },
                { "data": "cpanel_password" },
                { "targets": 0, "data": "download_link", "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                                                                                                                            return '<a href="'+data+'">Download</a>';
                                                                                                                        }                                                                                                           
                }
            ]
  });
```

Hope somebody may help me out. Thank you.

Comment: dataTables has nothing to do with bootstrap . Use `columns.render` ...numerous approaches here https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Comment: @charlietfl, according to your comment, I tried it like this -`{ "targets": 0, "data": "download_link", "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                               return '<a href="'+data+'">Download</a>';
                              }                           
    }`

Comment: But this is not working for me

Comment: what errors are thrown? ALso is there a property in your data to match "download_link" and I think data argument is an object

Comment: There is not a column name "download_link" in my database.

Comment: I think you can set to `data:null`. or leave that property out. I have sent dummy empty fields before from server with names like "blank" . I forget exactly what works. I do know that `render` will have an object that contains all the row data in one of the arguments so you can bind an id to a data attribute on your links